# Firestore from NDB with or without restrictions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, app-engine-ndb

Google announced automatic migration from Datastore to Firestore.
Its Datastore mode would be very nice because we will be freed from the restrictions such as the requirement of ancestor query in transactions, entity groups and so on.

We have tons of code using NDB. Will they remove the restrictions from NDB?

When?

Or do we need to switch to Cloud Datastore API or Firestore API?